# How to persist data in ruby on rails via through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I ve cretaed a active record relation ships among three entities as follows
and i want to persists data as follows and I managed to 
save data in to Transaction Group

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :reference, :transaction_group_id
  belongs_to :transaction_groups 
end


class TransactionGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :batch_id
  has_many :transactions, dependent => :destroy
end



class Batch < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :account_number, :file_name
  has_many :transaction_groups
  has_many :transactions , :through=>:ransaction_groups

  batch = Batch.new
  batch.account_number = "sessna"
  batch.transaction_groups.build(:batch_id => batch.id) 
end
```

But I could not figured out a way to save data in to Transaction entity via active records
  I tried

```
  batch.transaction_groups.transactions.build(:transaction_group_id => batch.transaction_groups.id) #this gaves me an error
```

How to persist data when a through association available?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: undefined method `transactions' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation